# undefined method `find' for Struct::Group:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting a find error which I can't figure out. It's working fine in rails console...

This is occurring in a library that is being called by delayed_job. Here's the full line:

```
@group = Group.find(:first, :conditions => ["uuid = ?", @uuid])
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

**Backtrace:**

```
{undefined method `find' for Struct::Group:Class
/Users/xxxxx/Sites/xxxxx/lib/mailing_job.rb:79:in `perform'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:87:in `invoke_job'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in `run'\n/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in `timeout'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in `run'\n/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/worker.rb:119:in `run'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/worker.rb:177:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/worker.rb:104:in `work_off'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in `times'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in `work_off'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/worker.rb:78:in `start'\n/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/worker.rb:77:in `start'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in `loop'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in `start'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bundler/gems/delayed_job-bb1e7803472b/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'\n/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31\n/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'\n/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: Maybe more of the backtrace might help.

Comment: sure thihg coming now...

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3):

According to the FAQ's in the [delayed_job docs](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/wiki)...

> There’s a strange edge-case with Ruby/Rails where Struct::Group already exists, so calling Group.anything from within a class that inherits from Struct will have strange results. You can workaround this issue by prefixing calls to Group with two colons. For example, ::Group.find would work as expected.

When this error rose for me I was calling 'Group' class methods inside a background job that inherited from a Struct. Prepending the classname with colons solved this issue.

Comment: Thank you.  Prepending Group with 2 colons solved my issue too.  Nice job.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for as well. Google'd "undefined method for Struct" and came across this post. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Supplying arguments such as :all, :first etc is deprecated in Rails 3. You should use something like this instead:

```
Group.first(:conditions => ["uuid = ?", @uuid])
```

Here is a few references of deprecated stuff: [active-record-query-interface](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface)

Comment: Upvote, because the OP didn't bother coming back. You get my karma.